# Case C# укоротить

Tags: c#, switch, case

Добрый день!

Есть такая конструкция

```
case "get_post_by_id":
  tcpTmp = new Post(new Parametr("id", attribute.FirstChild.InnerText));
  resalt = XMLtoString(((Post) tcpTmp).GetAsXml(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("access")  == "1"));
  _log.AddToLog((_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("login") != "NoAccess") ? int.Parse(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("id")) : 0, "Запрос на получение должности " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText);
break;
case "get_all_post":
  tcpTmp = new Post();
  resalt = XMLtoString(((Post) tcpTmp).GetAllAsXml(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("access")  == "1"));
  _log.AddToLog((_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("login") != "NoAccess") ? int.Parse(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("id")) : 0, "Запрос на получение всех должностей");
break;
case "get_departament_by_id":
  tcpTmp = new Departament(new Parametr("id", attribute.FirstChild.InnerText));
  resalt = XMLtoString(((Departament) tcpTmp).GetAsXml(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("access")  == "1"));
  _log.AddToLog((_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("login") != "NoAccess") ? int.Parse(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("id")) : 0, "Запрос на получение отдела " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText);
break;
case "get_all_departament":
  tcpTmp = new Departament();
  resalt = XMLtoString(((Departament) tcpTmp).GetAllAsXml(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("access")  == "1"));
  _log.AddToLog((_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("login") != "NoAccess") ? int.Parse(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("id")) : 0, "Запрос на получение всех отделов");
break;
....
и так дальше на 700 строк
```

Вот собственно и вопрос как можно это сократить конструкция примерно однотипная как можно заметить из примера.

```
tcpTmp - экземпляр родительского класса всех этих классов(Post, Departament, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case "get_post_by_id":
  tcpTmp = new Post(new Parametr("id", attribute.FirstChild.InnerText));
  resalt = XMLtoString(((Post) tcpTmp).GetAsXml(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("access")  == "1"));
  _log.AddToLog((_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("login") != "NoAccess") ? int.Parse(_user.Parametres.GetValueByName("id")) : 0, "Запрос на получение должности " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText);
break;
```

Можно попробовать заменить на

```
case "get_post_by_id":
  GetResult(new Post(new Parametr("id", attribute.FirstChild.InnerText)) ,
 "Запрос на получение должности " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText,
 1 );
break;
```

Где:

```
GetResult<T>(T model, string descForLog , int caseAllOr);
```

В котором:

1. T model - любая модель(можно и интерфейс сюда запихать вместо T.
2. string descForLog - descriptionForLog(описание для логирования)
3. int caseAllOr - где в строке resalt GetAsXml, а где то GetAllAsXml. Int - потому что могут быть еще варианты.

Либо(подчерпнул из другого ответа):

```
case "get_post_by_id":
      GetResult(typeof(Post) ,
     "Запрос на получение должности " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText,
     1 );
    break;
```

И внутри метода case c созданием разных типов, или:

```
case "get_post_by_id":
      GetResult(MODELS.Post ,
     "Запрос на получение должности " + attribute.FirstChild.InnerText,
     1 );
    break;
```

Где Models - Enum.
Но я бы максимум убрал бы log в красивую функцию, остальное может сильно меняться(смотрите по ситуации)

**UPD 3.**

Если испольльзовать файл со строками(которые для локализации используются), то можно вынести строки в отдельный файл, а ключом будут являться ваши case.

```
case "get_post_by_id":
      GetResult(MODELS.Post ,
     *переменная из switch*,
     1 );
    break;
```

А внутри метода по enum создавать(или typeof) создавать объект, по id искать строку(или использовать тут же enum, как в другом ответе предложили)

P.S. Смотрите по ситуации. Можно переборщить и любые изменения будут давать тяжко(любое отхождение от шаблона). Придется под каждое отхождение от шаблона делать изменения шаблона(ну или в таком case просто все по старому писать).

А если вы не сильно уменьшите читаемость, то и не стоит этого делать.

А про оптимизацию и ускорение - вообще третий вопрос и нужно намного больше инфы. Какой сервер, сколько нагрузки, часто ли и т.д.

UPD 4. Увеличивая таким образом читаемость - уменьшаете скорость. Смотрите по ситуации все.

Answer (score 0):

Упросить или ускорить? В заголовке одно, а в теле другое и это 2 совершенно разных понятия.

Если речь идет об упрощении, т.е сделать код более читабельным и самодокументированным, то очевидно, что нужно вынести логику каждого `CASE` в отдельный метод. Далее, внутри каждого метода ищем снова дублирующийся код и выносим в отдельные методы, делая декомпозицию.

Анализируемую строку так же лучше поменять на какой-нибудь `enum`- это упрастить рефакторинг.

Comment: А если ускорить то какую конструкцию использовать?

Comment: Бррррр... Только методов не хватало.

Comment: @Qwertiy с методами надо осторожнее. Можно просто для общих случаев сделать метод шаблон, а для экстровагантных методов оставить как есть. По сути ту же фабрику, может еще похоже на прототип шаблон.